# Remote actor respond with jobID and result future

Tags: scala, akka

Is it safe/viable to send a future in a message between remote Akka actors on different JVMs?  I suspect not.  So how can I achieve something like the following.  The key aspect is trying to have the reply (Ack) return both the future result, together with a reference to allow for cancellation.

```
case class BigJob()
case class Ack(jobId: Long, result: Future[Int])
case class Cancel(jobID: Long)

val ack = (remoteActor ? BigJob()).mapTo[Ack]

if(changedMyMind) remoteActor ! Cancel(ack.jobID)
else ack.result foreach println
```

**Update:** Am using Scala 2.10.1 and Akka 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remote actor you could use additional waiting actor:

```
var myActor = actor {
  var waitingSender: Option[OutputChannel[Any]] = None
  var result: Option[BigJobResult] = None
  val jobID = remoteActor !? StartBigJob() match { case l: Long => l }
  loop {
    react {
      case "stop" =>
        remoteActor ! Cancel(jobID)
        exit
      case "getResult" => result match {
        case Some(r) =>
          sender ! r
          exit
        case None => waitingSender = Some(sender)
      }
      case r: BigJobResult => waitingSender match {
        case Some(s) =>
          s ! r
          exit
        case None => result = Some(BigJobResult)
      }
    }
  }
}.start 

if(changedMyMind) myActor ! "stop" 
else myActor !? "getResult" ...
```

**Update**: Using `akka`.

```
case object ChangedMyMind
case object GetResult
case object BigJob
case class BigJobResult(i: Int)
case class Cancel(jobId: Long)
case class JobStarted(jobId: Long)

val remoteActor = actor( new Act {
  become {
    case c: Cancel => println(c); context.stop(self)
    case BigJob =>
      val target = sender
      sender ! JobStarted(666)
      Future{ Thread.sleep(10000); target ! BigJobResult(13) }
  }
})

val a = actor(new ActWithStash {
  whenStarting { remoteActor ! BigJob }
  become {
    case JobStarted(jobId) => unstashAll(); becomeStacked {
      case ChangedMyMind => remoteActor ! Cancel(jobId); context.stop(self)
      case r: BigJobResult => unstashAll(); becomeStacked {
        case GetResult => sender ! r; context.stop(self)
        case ChangedMyMind => context.stop(self)
      }
      case GetResult => stash()
    }
    case ChangedMyMind | BigJobResult(_) | GetResult => stash()
  }
})

if(changedMyMind) a ! ChangedMyMind
else (a ? GetResult) foreach println
```

Comment: Thanks, I presume this is using Scala Actors.  I'll try to understand the essence and see if the additional actor trick will solve my need for cancellation.  Have update my question for clarity.

Comment: @Pengin: they are pretty similar, [aren't they](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html)? Updated.

Comment: I think I get it now, and thanks to your example learnt about stacked behaviours.  So, I can use an intermediate actor.  If A is the calling actor, B is the intermediate, and C is the remote 'worker' then… A fires up B and can use an ask for sending the job, getting back a future to the result.  B sends the request on to C and gets back job ID for cancellation.  A can initiate the cancellation with B, or just wait for the result to come back.  Great stuff.

Comment: @Pengin: be careful with `ActWithStash`. There is [a bug](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/3199-actwithstash-ignores-whenstopping-and-whenrestarted#/activity/ticket:) in it.

Comment: Sending a Future in a message may well be thread-safe, but it will never work across remoting: the deserialized future will NOT be completed when the original is. Please remove those first five paragraphs from your answer because they are really misleading. Concerning cancellation of the BigJob: that only works if the job processing is chunked by sending continuation messages to self; the future you show cannot be cancelled. The rest is good, though.

Comment: @RolandKuhn. there was "on single jvm" in first part, but you are correct: it's off topic, deleted. `remoteActor` implementation is only for testing and message types illustration.

Comment: If you use remoting—even within the same jvm—then it will not work because after serialization/deserialization you have two decoupled Futures instead of one. Thanks for correcting!

Comment: @RolandKuhn, thank you for explanation. I didn't notice that.